# Can't read in one .dat file to create a second .dat file

Tags: c++, file-io

Trying to read in one file using a while loop (it's called "Stocks.dat" and the reason I'm using a while-loop is because in the future, X amount of stocks may be appended; the format of the .dat file is listed below) to create a second file "profits.dat" which contains the information of "Stocks.dat" but with new calculation floats. This **runs** fine, but when I check to see if "profits.dat" exists, there is nothing there. Why am I not getting a "profits.dat" file with all the calculations inside? Thanks so much.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[40];
    int sh;
    float pp, cp, pc, cv, pr;

    ifstream infile("c:\\Stocks.dat", ios::in);
    ofstream outfile("c:\\profits.dat", ios::out);


    while (infile.getline(name, 40)) //don't forget the whitespace
    {
    infile >> sh >> pp >> cp;
    pc = sh * pp;
    cv = sh * cp;
    pr = cv - pc;
    outfile << name << endl; //need the endline
    outfile << pc << ' ' << cv << ' ' << pr << ' ' << endl; //need the blank spaces
    infile.ignore(40, '\n');
    }

    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}

//Stocks.dat information:
//APPLE
//500 20.25 30.75
//MICROSOFT
//250 9.75 12.99
//GOOGLE
//1000 50.10 300.85
```

Comment: Does `outfile.fail() == false`? Maybe lack of permission to write on `C:`. Try desktop. Works as expected on my machine but with paths changed to desktop

Comment: Not sure what you're saying? How would I give permission to write on C:? I've made read/write programs before, and it would save it in the project folder, but "profits.dat" is not in the project folder. What do you mean by "try desktop"?

Comment: Tried changing the path to desktop and no dice :(

Comment: I mean that your program may not have enough permission to open a file for writing or create it directly at path `C:`. Okay you tried and it didn't work. What is returned by `outfile.fail()` after constructing the object? Add it to the question.

Comment: So I create an if statement for `outfile.fail()` and it returned my cout "Couldn't open the file!" so yeah, it's not opening the file....what should I do?

Comment: put in  call to perror after the open that is failing to get a human readable error message that should explain why the open failed.

Comment: Uhm, can you translate that for me? I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to say .

Comment: By the way, you don't need endl. It is a line feed and a stream flush. You don't wan't to flush to a file unless you need to because it is sickeningly expensive. Recommend replacing endl with '\n'

Comment: `'Stocks.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.`

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror prints a nice, easy to read message for the last error. it can tell you why the file wouldn't open.

Comment: Pdb is a debugger file. you don't have debugging info for the listed dll. Don't worry about it. you don't need it.

Comment: Interesting: the perror said "`Permission Denied`"...what am I to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137116/discussion-between-polymorphism-and-user4581301).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely the problem with permissions. Your `ofstream` fails to open a file for writing at location `C:` - writing directly to your system drive requires administrator privileges (I think starting from Windows Vista but I'm not sure).

You may run your program as administrator or place the file (change the path as opening for writing will create a file) in a location where you can write.

**EDIT:**

Change this

```
ofstream outfile("c:\\profits.dat", ios::out);
```

to this

```
ofstream outfile("c:\\users\\YOUR_USER\\desktop\\profits.dat", ios::out);
```

or some other location where you can write without administrator privileges. You can find such location by opening `notepad` and trying to save file. If you can save file in that location your program will create `profits.dat` there successfully.

Comment: Stuck the `Stocks.dat` to the desktop, and I'm still getting "permission denied" error. I also was sure to change the file path inside the code.

Comment: I'm trying to have my code create a file called `profits.dat` with all the new calculations in it along with the relevant stock info.

Comment: @polymorphism change the path that you pass to your `ofstream` constructor to desktop or first run the program as administrator to see that it really fixes the issue.

Comment: Right, but it's the file you can't open to write so long as it is going to be written to the root of C. Don't write there an problem goes away. Unless you choose to write to another restricted location.

Comment: I did change it to the long path name for both ifstream and ofstream, but still no dice; also i can't open it up using administrator, windows throws an error

Comment: @polymorphism edited the answer, you have a way to find a proper location at the end of my answer. **please note that your stocks.dat must be copied into that location as well if you change the path for ifstream** - to keep things simple, don't touch your `stocks.dat` and `ifstream` at all, make it as it is in example.

Comment: I made a sample text file and I could save there, but it still isn't working.

Comment: @polymorphism update the code in the question to match your current code.

Comment: I did. For both ifstream and ofstream.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137117/discussion-between-polymorphism-and-mpiatek).